# HTML field appendix with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to append "years" on the back of a html field containing the number of years.

Something like a placeholder of sorts.

Is that possible with CSS or HTML?

I dont really want to create a floating  or some thing like that.

Im not saying give me the code to do it. Im asking is it possible and what is the thing I can read up about then. obviously using a word "appender" show that I dont know what its called. Mr Downvoter

Comment: `<input placeholder="Years" />`... you mean that?

Comment: Not a place holder, that will dissapear after entry. I need the word to remain after entry

Comment: Would that not be extremely off putting? Also I think you will have to use floating labels, I don't see another way around it.

Comment: In the context of how I want to use it I dong think. 3 fields (year, Month, Day), with the "field identifier" appended to the number and only Age as the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not completely possible, but definitely possible without going the whole floating  way

```
.age_inner_label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 18px;
}



.age_Box{
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: none;
}
```

Two fields edited to look like one.

[image]
Might not look spectacular, but it does what I asked.